# Are "Document Types" working in iOS 16 and iOS 17?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios16, ios16.4

I have problems making "Document Types" property to work on iOS. My goal is to show my app in the Share dialog appearing when user taps on an image in their Photos gallery and then taping on the Share menu item.

Despite setting Document Types option in my Info.plist file, my app still doesn't appear on the Share screen. Here are my Document Type settings:

[image: Document Types setting in XCode for iOS 17]

I also noticed that Target - Info - Document Types editor is broken in XCode. Does it mean this feature is no longer supported in iOS 16?

Comment: You need to write a share extension.